# Is information security based entirely on mathematics

Tags: cryptography

I started to show interest in information security few months ago, the more I read the more I think it's all about mathematics not information techonolgy. I mean the whole thing is based on encryption and the latter is just a set of complicated mathematical equations.

To be more specific why do we see IT gurus in conventions talking about how they developed strong encryption .. etc when it only the work of math scientists? and when someone says that NSA can break X encryption it means they have a team of mathematicians who have came up with an equation that breaks the first one. What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't forget about [physical information security](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_information_security) (to a person, to papers, to a server, to a network, etc.) encryption is only part of (electronic) information security. Think for example about security policies (access rights) that have no direct relation to mathematics/encryption.

Comment: Well there's a reason that Math is a required course(s) for engineering/computer science.

Comment: Encryption is not the only aspect of information security. Information Security is very broad and there are tons of InfoSec things that have nothing to do with math. How much math do you need to secure a network. Probably not much. If you go down deep enough, everything is a 1 or a 0, but that doesn't mean computer problems are math problem.

Comment: False assumption; Information security is far more than encryption.  Just as a trivial example, information security includes availability, and encryption doesn't help availability.  Even the best encryption in the universe is worthless if the key for the encryption is leaked, and no amount of math will affect whether someone with the key leaks the key.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a general lack of understanding about the fundamentals of information security.

Comment: Why do you believe that an IT guru couldn't/wouldn't come up with their own encryption algorithm? Why do you believe that an IT guru couldn't also have a background in math?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the commenters have mentioned, information security is much more than cryptography. I can think of huge swathes of the field that do not necessarily have to include cryptography, or to which cryptography isn't really part of at all:

- Security policy
- Regulatory compliance
- Physical security
- Web application security
- Binary application security
- Network security
- Industrial control security
- Operational security
- Threat intelligence
- Malware analysis and reverse engineering
- Secure destruction of data
- Digital forensics
- Development of security products (WAF, AV, IDS, IPS, etc.)
- etc, etc, etc...

So no, information security is not just cryptography, and even cryptography is not just mathematics. The core primitives of crypto may well be deeply rooted in maths, but topics like PKI have logical, financial, political, commercial, and human aspects to them.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. Strong and good encryption is very important, and is probably a key requirement for good security, but there is so much more. Think of protocols. SSL, TLS, handshakes, how to exchange keys in a secure way. These are all examples of information security technology that is not encryption technique but uses it.

Think of file ownership and file rights on a server, which user can see or do what?! That has nothing to do with encryption, but is very much about security.

These are just two examples I can think of. There are probably many more...

Answer (score 0):

NO absolutely not , information security bases on mathematics in the cryptography side  yes , but there still a so much bigger world in the security when mathematics is not used , and as Polynomial mentioned examples ,cryptography is just a small part in the security world , but an important one .